# Bash "or" statement and "date -I" flag

Tags: bash, date, if-statement

What I am trying to do it check certain files in a directory and see if they are created today or yesterday. 
I know that you can use find, this is part of a larger script.

```
#!/bin/bash

volume="/home/casper/data/vol14/"
dirLimit="casper_limit/"
dirConsu="casper_consumption/"
nowMonth=$(/bin/date +'%b' -d 'now')
preMonth=$(/bin/date +'%b' -d 'last month')
tradeDay=$(/bin/date -I)
previDay=$(/bin/date -I -d 'yesterday')
limtfile="CASPER_LIMIT_01*.journal"


cd $volume$limit
for journal in $limtfile
    do
    modtime=$(/bin/date -I -r  $journal)
    if [[ "$modtime" == "$tradeDay" || "$previDay" ]] ; then
echo "$journal is $modtime"
fi
done
```

Presently the "or" statement does not work, it prints out ever file. 
In addition, I picked up the date -I a while ago, which prints out the day in this format YYYY-MM-DD. I do not see the '-I' flag in the man pages. Is there a shortcut flag for YYYY.MM.DD ? Does anyone know what these shortcuts are called and is there a list of these shortcut delimiters like '-I'.

Comment: Your IF condition looks like this:  `IF [[ condition_1_whatever_it_is OR "$previday" ]]`. `"$previday"` will exit with success if the variable exists, and failure if the variable does not exist. In your case it does exist, so the compound condition in IF is always true.

Comment: Also: if your list of possible values you need to check grows, doing this with an `IF` statement will keep getting more and more painful. In that case, you might want to consider a `CASE` statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `==` *twice*; the `||` joins two comparisons, not two right-hand arguments to `==`.

```
if [[ "$modtime" == "$tradeDay" || "$modtime" == "$previDay" ]]; then
```